# how can i convert hexadecimal number to binary using bit-mask

Tags: c, binary, hex

```
int main()
{
    double hexa_number;
    double bitmask = 0x80;
    double i;
    printf("Enter 8 bit number in hexadecimal form: ");
    scanf("%lf",& hexa_number);
    for( i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
    {
        if(hexa_number&(bitmask >> i))
            printf("1");
        else
            printf("0");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

plus Displaying the binary representation of this number, 
  along with a count of the number of 0’s and 1’s in the binary number.
  i found other ways to convert it but not with bitmask

Comment: I've retagged this as C, not C# since there's no `printf` in C#.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that you are using a double for your bitmask. I don't think >> makes much sense for doubles especially as they are composed of a sign bit, mantissa and 2^ exponent.

For example, 8 >> 1 is 4. That is a nice consistent operation, same as division by 2.

If we imagine an unsigned two byte float for simplicity and imagine that the first byte represents the mantissa and the second the exponent (both unsigned), then 7 * 2^4 (=112) could be represented as 0b00000111 00000100. If you shift that 1 to the right, >> 1, you will get 0b00000011 10000010, which by our convention is now 3 * 2^130. This is definitely not the division by 2 you would get by shifting an integer right by 1.

My compiler gives "error: invalid operands to binary >> (have double and unsigned)" if I try bitwise shifting a floating point number.

So basically you could try the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int hexa_number = 0;
    unsigned num_bits = sizeof(int)*8;
    unsigned bitmask = 1 << (num_bits - 1);
    printf("Enter a number in hexadecimal form: ");
    scanf("%i", &hexa_number);

    unsigned k = 0;
    unsigned num_ones = 0;
    unsigned num_zeros = 0;

    for(k = 0; k != num_bits; k ++)
    {
        if(hexa_number & (bitmask >> k))
        {
            printf("1");
            num_ones ++;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("0");
            num_zeros++;
        }
    }
    printf("\nNumber of ones is %i\nNumber of zeros is %i", num_ones, num_zeros);
    return 0;
}
```